# Торговый робот на c#

Tags: .net, mql

Доброго дня. Есть задача - написать простенького торгового робота для metatrader. Возможно ли это, не используя встроенный скриптовый язык MQL, а с помощью, например .net или java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не специалист в этой области, но как то получал похожий опыт в академических целях.

Если задача написать простенького робота, и нужно обязательно использовать metatrader, то лучше используете MQL и не заморачивайтесь. Для него есть куча примеров, документация и хорошая интеграция с платформой, тестирование на исторических данных.

Если metatrader не обязателен, можете попробовать [Oanda](https://www.oanda.com) - у этого брокера есть HTTP API, и уже готовый SDK для Java

Answer (score 0):

В метатрейдере торговые стратегии пишутся только на встроенном языке MQL4/5 и компилируются в файлы с расширением ex4/ex5.

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас появилась такая возможность - вы можете использовать Java или C# для написания своей стратегии, и общаться напрямую с сервером Metatrader 4/5. Компания mtapi.tech предоставляет библиотеку и примеры её использования, в том числе скачивание исторических данных и получение информации о счете.

Всё остальное - индикаторы и стратегии, базирующиеся на них, вы можете написать самостоятельно, или использовать имеющиеся библиотеки типа [TA4J](https://github.com/ta4j/ta4j)/[Stock.Indicators](https://github.com/DaveSkender/Stock.Indicators).